# Get x/y/z from coordinates for tile image

Tags: objective-c, mapbox

How can I retrieve ***x***, ***y*** and ***z*** for RMTile struct using coordinates (latitude, longitude)?
I use this for downloading tile images.
How I did that before - just switched RMMapView's *debugTiles* property to *YES* and then watched on map on screen.

```
RMTile tile = RMTileMake(x, y, z);
UIImage *image = [self.mapView.tileSource imageForTile:tile inCache:self.mapView.tileCache];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see a way that we've done this here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk/blob/release/MapView/Map/RMInteractiveSource.m#L119-L172 You will need to use `RMMapView` to convert your latitude/longitude into a `CGPoint` first, though.

Comment: But I need to Exact opposite to that, I Have tile_column, tile_row and Zoom_level and I need to find out Latitude&Longitude of Particular tile location exact    any one Know please reply Here